# OpenLayers + GEOExt + extjs. VS OpenLayers+jquery

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js, jquery

Could some one maybe tell me if there are any real benefits of using OpenLayers + GEOExt + extjs. as oppose to using only OpenLayers and maybe jquery for client side webgis apps?

Edit: thanks for replying guys. I'm doing my graduation project which will be a web app for finding the best bus route to do a certain trip and route the user to the departure stop from the departure point and from the destination stop to the destination point. There are 3 layers one for the good looking map from osm, one from my roads containing the topology and one from the stops, i'll be using pgrouting and postgres+ postgis for the database.

Comment: I think the answer will be "well it depends what you are doing", so I'd suggest extending your question above (just click "edit" link) to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Agree with BradHards. ExtJS and jQuery are completly different frameworks for completly different tasks. When you know, what your application is going to be, then it's easy to choose between them.

Comment: I had a great experience with Openlayers + ExtJS + GeoExt. Pretty complete and simple. I want to start an application with JQuery + Openlayers though, to avoid that "desktop appearance". Good luck for your project!

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to at first, but the area you have written this is reserved for direct Answers to the Question posed.  Consequently, it would have been better as a Comment but even more preferable would have been to simply upvote the Question or Answer(s) if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Before you figure out which one to use, you need to understand the difference between jQuery and ExtJs. jQuery includes features like DOM Manipulation, Event Handling, AJAX and allows it to be Extended through plugins. On its own, it includes very little UI components.

ExtJs on the other hand is a complete framework, which includes all of the above, and additionally several UI components.

Using both of them with OpenLayers is very much possible. You have already mentioned the GeoExt project, which uses the ExtJS libraries along with OpenLayers Library. It also includes server GIS specific components like TOC, Legend etc.

For jQuery, there is a project called [MapQuery](http://mapquery.org/).  I personally have absolutely no experience with it, but on a brief review, it looks like it does not have much inbuilt UI components.

With this information in mind, you need to figure out how heavy your application will be in terms of UI Component. Looking at your edit, I don't think it needs any specific UI components besides the map.

I think it could be done with just the OpenLayers Library.